# Error in assignment to expression with array type

Tags: arrays, c, variable-assignment, c-strings, string-literals

I am trying to code a program that shows the Easter day when the user inputs the year between 1991 and 2099. All are good but when I am trying to run the program, it says there is an error: assignment to expression with array type. How can I fix this? and what is the wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char month[50];
int year, day;
printf("Please enter a year between 1990 and 2099: ");
scanf("%d", &year);


int a = year-1900;
int b = a%19;
int c = (7*b+1)/19;
int d = (11*b+4-c)%29;
int e = a/4;
int f = (a+e+31-d)%7;
int g = 25 - (d + f);

if (g <= 0 )
{
    month = "March";
    day = 31 + g;
}
else
{
    month = "April";
    day = g;
}
    printf("The date is %s %d", month, day);

}
```

Comment: You don't assign to strings with `=`, you use `strcpy()`.

Comment: You could also change it to a pointer variable: `char *month`.

Comment: Thank you, it runs now

Comment: It's best to avoid rolling your own calendar functions. Calendars are weird. In this case it will probably barely suffice, though.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf` etc., and abort (e.g. `abort();`) on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues.

To change the content of an array use for example the standard string function `strcpy`.

```
#include <string.h >

//...

strcpy( month, "March" );
```

An alternative approach is to declare the variable month as a pointer. For example

```
char *month;
```

or (that is better)

```
const char *month;
```

In this case you may write

```
month = "March";
```

Comment: "lvalue" literally means "can be used on the LHS of an assignment". Did you mean "rvalue"?

Comment: @ikegami No according to the C Standard arrays are non-modifiable lvalues.

Comment: Ok, but how odd

Comment: @ikegami The origin of the terms refers to where they appear in assignments, language details sometimes make those meanings not apply. An lvalue is an expression that denotes a memory location, while an rvalue is a value without an associated location (it can be a temporary value from an expression).